# Solving ill conditioned linear system in maple

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, maple, regularization

I want to solve the linear system of equation

$$AX=B$$[image]

with (Condition Number(A)=7.36*10^25) in maple 12, please help me.
thanks.

Comment: Why does "Condition Number(A)" have anything to do with solving the equations? And see [this](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=MTM/rref) for solving them.

Comment: @Lovsovs the condition number is a rough measure of how "difficult" it is to solve a matrix equation. A high condition number means the numerical inversion will be ill-conditioned and introduce a lot of error. To OP, the numbers in the matrices are so tiny that anything numeric will introduce a lot of error, both $A$ and $B$ are effectively all zero. I don't know how you might get an accurate result for this computation.

Comment: @David Interesting, thanks for letting me know! :)

Comment: How did you get your matrix? Maybe you could precondition it analytically.

Answer (score 2):

Read your book my friend... If $A$ is invertible, then $X=A^{-1}B$. Assume that you want to calculate $X$ with $3$ significant digits (denoted by s.d.); since  $B$ is also known with $3$ s.d., it suffices to calculate $A^{-1}$ with $3$ s.d.. Assume that $A$ is known with $k$ s.d.; since $cond(A)\approx 10^{26}$, $A^{-1}$ is known with $k-26$ s.d. and finally, the required condition (about $k$) is $k\geq 29$. It seems that you know only $3$ s.d. of $A$; then you cannot do it (as Obama).